useEffect and dispatch with asyncThunk not working. What am i doing wrong?
In my code below i am using useEffect with dispatch and inside the dispatch function I am using an asyncThunk. If i console.log, in the fulfilled function provided by the thunk, the user then i get the correct data in the payload and in the state.user.
import {Navigate} from "react-router-dom";
import {useDispatch, useSelector} from "react-redux";
import {useEffect} from "react";
import {fetchUserData} from "../../redux/slices/authSlice";

const PrivateRoute = ({children}) => {

    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    const {
        user,
        loading,
        error
    } = useSelector((state) => state.auth);

    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(fetchUserData());
    }, [user, dispatch]);

    console.log(user);
    if (loading) {
        return <div>Loading...</div>;
    }

    if (error) {
        return <div>Error: {error}</div>;
    }

    return user ? children : <Navigate to="/auth" />;
};

export default PrivateRoute;

The code below is my auth slice
import {createAsyncThunk, createSlice} from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

const authSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'auth',
    initialState: {
        user: null,
        loading: false,
        error: null,
    },
    reducers: {
        logout(state) {
            state.user = null;
        },
    },
    extraReducers: (builder) => {
        builder
            .addCase(fetchUserData.pending, (state) => {
                state.loading = true;
                state.error = null;
            })
            .addCase(fetchUserData.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
                state.user = action.payload;
                state.loading = false;
            })
            .addCase(fetchUserData.rejected, (state, action) => {
                state.loading = false;
                state.user = null;
                state.error = action.payload || 'Failed to fetch user data';
            });
    },
});

export const fetchUserData = createAsyncThunk('fetchUserData', async (_, thunkAPI) => {
    try {
        const response = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/auth/verifyToken', {
            credentials: 'include',
        });

        if (!response.ok) {
            return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue('Failed to fetch user data');
        }

        return await response.json();
    } catch (error) {
        return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(error.message);
    }
});

export const authActions = authSlice.actions;
export const authReducer = authSlice.reducer;

I tried using async await inside the useEffect function. I also tried using middleware in the store but i was getting errors. Am i doing anything wrong?

state.auth.loading is initially false, and state.auth.error is null, e.g. falsey, and state.auth.user is null, e.g. also falsey, so your PrivateRoute component renders the redirect to the "/auth" route. I suggest starting with state.auth.user being initially undefined, e.g. neither a defined user object or null, and update the loading condition to if (loading || user === undefined) so then the app mounts and hasn't populated the user state yet it doesn't just immediately bounce the user off the route.

@DrewReese thank you for your answer. That actually worked. Could you please explain  it to me a bit more? (if you have the time of course). I am new to redux and react and i need some help. Thank you in advance

Sure, though I thought the comment was thorough enough. Can you let me know what specifically is still a bit unclear for you?

@DrewReese I feel like I need to understand the last part. The part that you talk about how the app mounts. Basically the last sentence :)

When the component mounts and does the initial render pass, all the state values used for the auth checks (e.g. loading, error, and user) are all false/falsey, so the Navigate component is rendered and the user is navigated off the route. The last sentence says to include the undefined user "state" in the loading check so that if/when user is actually defined the last check can render either children or the Navigate component. Does this make sense?

@DrewReese thank you for your help. Sorry for the late response :). I think i got it now. There's one more thing thought that is not part of the question I asked but i would appreciate if you could answer me. So basically in my project what i do is render the PrivateRoute first, before any other component. Is it okay to check every time if I have a user and use the fetchUserData  thunk which makes a call to the backend to check for my cookies and tokens? Thank you!!!!

That's a perfectly valid security implementation, but the trade-off is all route transitions may be slower or display the loading indicator each time.

@DrewReese yeah i noticed that it shows the loading indicator each time even for a fraction of a second. Is there anything else I could do or should i stick with it for now?

Another option is to run the auth logic higher up the ReactTree and provide it downstream via a React context/Redux/etc and just check the current state/value/auth status synchronously. There's not much between the two patterns.
